# Extracting specific registry key from REG QUERY based on search string

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd, registry

I am trying to extract the key value of a registry entry. I only want the key which I have been trying to concatenate using **`FOR /F`**, however had no luck.

**Eg: the command**

**`REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s /f chrome`**

**returns**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{157F97DF-A001-36FB-A90C-55949FA130CA}
DisplayName    REG_SZ    Google Chrome
End of search: 1 match(es) found.
```

---

All that I want from this result is **`157F97DF-A001-36FB-A90C-55949FA130CA`**

How can I do this using **`FOR /F`** or other similar methods?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to split the lines using `{}` as delimiters

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2 delims={}" %%a in ('
        REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s /f chrome
    ') do set "value=%%a"

    echo %value%
```